# Center Icons in Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to center some icons in bootstrap columns, and they are centered when the page is large, but when the width gets smaller the icons shade to the right inside their columns. This might be hopeless, but is there any way for me to keep the icons centered no matter the size of the window?

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="row text-center" style="padding: 4px 2.5em 4px 2.5em;">

    <div class="col-xs-3 text-center">
         <a class="subtle-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <a class="subtle-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <a class="subtle-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-3">
         <a class="subtle-link" href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus-square"></i></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is a jFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ufoa55d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of left and right paddings in the bootstrap "col-xs-3" style.
I added this css to your fiddle, and it works fine for me:

```
.icons-group .col-xs-3 {
    padding: 0;
}
```

also i marked your

```
<div class="row text-center icons-group" style="padding: 4px 3em 4px 3em;">
```

div with "icons-group" style to set scope for above css.